# Converting error to boxed when inside a collection

Tags: rust

I have a function that reads a file line by line and parses. Right now to `i32` but really I'd like this to be templated. Just keeping things simple for now.

I can get it sorted out using explicit for-loops, but not using iterators.

The below code complains that the error type can't be converted to the `Box<dyn Error>` type and I'm not sure what to do about that. Aren't the parse errors part of the standard library and thus implement the `Error` trait, and doesn't `Box` do automatic conversion of errors (because it's such a common idiom?)

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f663890d51abb0822427785c31dca259)

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;

pub fn read_file_to_list(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_as_string = fs::read_to_string(filename)?;
    file_as_string.lines().map(|line| line.parse()).collect()
}
```

Error is in the `parse`:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<i32 as FromStr>::Err == Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:44
  |
6 |     file_as_string.lines().map(|line| line.parse()).collect()
  |                                            ^^^^^ expected struct `ParseIntError`, found struct `Box`
  |
  = note: expected struct `ParseIntError`
             found struct `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
```

I assume I'll need to do some sort of `map_err` but I can't figure out what and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, conversion from `ParseIntError` to `Box<dyn Error>` can be done using the `Into` trait as there is a [blanket impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) for that in the stdlib. So we can  replace `line.parse()` with

```
line.parse().map_err(|e| e.into())
```

or:

```
line.parse().map_err(Into::into)
```

A common trick to make this more ergonomic is abusing the fact that `?` automatically calls `.into()` on the error type:

```
Ok(line.parse()?)
```

It looks a bit silly to use `?` only to wrap in `Ok`, but it's actually a common idiom precisely for this purpose. So this compiles:

```rust
pub fn read_file_to_list(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_as_string = fs::read_to_string(filename)?;
    file_as_string.lines().map(|line| Ok(line.parse()?)).collect()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was expecting the `into` part to magically happen. Now for replacing `i32` with `T` was a bit tricky too. Of course we need `T: FromStr` so it works with parse; but I also had to add a strange bound (with `'static`) to the lifetime of the error type: `<T as FromStr>::Err : Error + 'static`